# docker-composed built flask with mongoEngine, trying connect but returned pymongo error?

Tags: mongodb, flask, docker-compose

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6173037b75e69e32feeca143, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 671, in error_router
    return original_handler(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 669, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 671, in error_router
    return original_handler(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 669, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 403, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 83, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restx/resource.py", line 49, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/auth/controller.py", line 35, in post
    return AuthService.login(login_data)
  File "/app/auth/service.py", line 16, in login
    user = User.objects(username='daas').first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py", line 38, in __get__
    queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 215, in _get_collection
    db = cls._get_db()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 193, in _get_db
    return get_db(cls._meta.get("db_alias", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 364, in get_db
    conn_settings["username"], conn_settings["password"], **auth_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 1581, in authenticate
    connect=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 810, in _cache_credentials
    writable_preferred_server_selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 246, in select_server
    address))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 203, in select_servers
    selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 220, in _select_servers_loop
    (self._error_message(selector), timeout, self.description))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6173037b75e69e32feeca143, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

docker-compose file

```
   api:
    build: api
    image: azurecr.io/api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - "ENV=prod"
      - "DB_USERNAME=name"
      - "DB_PASSWORD=password"
      - "DB_HOST=mongodb"
    depends_on:
      - "mongodb"
 mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    command: mongod
    environment:
      - "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=name"
      - "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you set a MongoDB connection string. It isn't picking up the `DB_HOST` as you expect (it's defaulting to `localhost`).

If you can edit your question add in the lines where you're making the MongoDB connection then that would help.

Comment: // for init db connection, simply load this config into app.py I've turned on local mongoservice
//I also tried command: mongod --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 in docker-compose, nor MONGO_HOST = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongodb', none of them works
//authentication fail all the time

// config
class ProductionConfig(Config):
+    MONGODB_HOST = 'mongodb://mongodb/prod'
+    MONGODB_USERNAME = os.getenv("DB_USERNAME")
+    MONGODB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")

//app
app.config.from_object(config_by_name[os.getenv('ENV') or 'default'])
db.init_app(app)

Comment: Possibly your mixing up MONGO_HOST, MONGODB_HOST and DB_HOST environment variables somewhere.

Comment: if I was using mysql, I don't even need to add these items, just db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306" and it will work